# How to Write unit test case for native selenium methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

Basically I am a QA recently built a framework with base methods which will make our testers live easy where they can call and write a one liner.
I have been given a task to write unit test cases for these methods nw.

Google/youtube talks lot abt JUnit but I am not getting how a unit test case be for a method like this

```
public void iType(WebElement ele, String data, String elementName) {

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
            ele.clear();
            ele.sendKeys(data);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect your testers to call this method? In a unit test, you call the method just like you would from code that is intended to use that method. You need to create valid parameters to pass into the method. Then you call the method with those parameters. Finally, you verify that the result after calling the method is correct.

Comment: My testers will just call this method as itype(elementname,"datatobepassed","string to say which elmenttyping") Elementname will be identified using @FindBy

Comment: A unit test will just call the function exactly in the same way. For a "happy" test, you should verify that the passed in element does in fact contain the data that was supposed to be typed into it. Error tests can include things like passing in an element that isn't visible or isn't clickable and verifying that the wait times out.

Answer (score 0):

In a unit test, you call the method just like you would from code that is intended to use that method. You need to create valid parameters to pass into the method. Then you call the method with those parameters. Finally, you verify that the result after calling the method is correct.